# AFNetworking low memory issue

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uicollectionview, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I download image using this code:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    SECustomCollectionViewCell *collectionViewCell = (SECustomCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"SECustomCollectionViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDictionary *artwork = [self.artworks objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];

    collectionViewCell.theImageView.image = nil;

    if (artwork[@"video_url"])
    {
        UIWebView *webView = (UIWebView *)[collectionViewCell.contentView viewWithTag:100];
        NSString * html = [self embedYouTube:artwork[@"video_url"] frame:collectionViewCell.frame];

        [webView setHidden:NO];

        [webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];

        [collectionViewCell.activityIndicator setHidden:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:artwork[@"image_url"]]];

        UIImage *cachedImage = [[[UIImageView class] sharedImageCache] cachedImageForRequest:request];

        if (cachedImage)
        {
            collectionViewCell.theImageView.image = [UIImage scaleImage:cachedImage toWidth:collectionViewCell.frame.size.width];
            [collectionViewCell.activityIndicator setHidden:YES];
        }
        else
        {
            [collectionViewCell.theImageView setImageWithURLRequest:request placeholderImage:nil success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, UIImage *image) {

                // Only update visible cell, to avoid inserting image to another cell.
                SECustomCollectionViewCell *visibleCollectionViewCell = (id)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];

                if (visibleCollectionViewCell)
                {
                    [visibleCollectionViewCell.theImageView setImage:[UIImage scaleImage:image toWidth:collectionViewCell.frame.size.width]];

                    [visibleCollectionViewCell.activityIndicator stopAnimating];

                    [visibleCollectionViewCell.activityIndicator setHidden:YES];
                }

            } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

            }];
        }
    }

    return collectionViewCell;
}
```

but it cause low memory issues.

Comment: How big is the file? Files of substantial size are best downloaded by streaming directly to a file. There is a lot of computation going on the the main thread including image scaling.

Comment: @Zaph I have jpeg file on server that is 1.4MB but XCode says tahat there 70MB after load it to imageview

Comment: So it is not AFNetworking but the image code that is causing the memory usage. How big is the image? JPEG or PNG, etc compresses images but when an image is created there will be 4-bytes per pixel. There is scaling going on which will also use memory. You should probably put autorelease pools around the scaling methods so the memory is released early.

Comment: @Zaph it is 5407 × 3605, but after I donwload it I try to resize it and set image view new smaller image. But I think the afnetworking loads a data that is still big. And when collection view tried to upload 10 images it is big amount. I agree with, but how can I handle it. I mean, maybe I need to wait while one image will be uploaded and then resize it. After uploading first image and resizing it app should move forward and upload second image and do the same as for first and next the same for all images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not AFNetworking but the image code that is causing the memory usage. JPEG compresses images but when an image is created there will be 4-bytes per pixel. Since the jpeg file on server that is 1.4MB that is all AFNetworking will load.

It seems you are using some helper class look at that code and NSLog the size of the actual data that AFNetworking downloads.

An image of 5407 × 3605 at 4 bytes per pixel will create an image of over 77MB. You can scale it but first the original image is rendered and the scaling will use more memory because at the end you will have two images.

You need to wrap the creation of the original image and the scaling in an autorelease pool so the original is released as soon as possible.

Best is not to load such a large image in the first place.